# 68 series CPU vs 80 series CPU

Tags: avr, lcd, atmel, interface

I'm reading a lot of LCD driver data sheets at the moment and they often have multiple interfaces (serial, 8-bit, 16-bit, etc...).

They are also often also split into two sections "80 series CPU" and "68 series CPU" but I can't find any information on what that actually means.

What is the difference and how do I identify which is appropriate for my application (Ateml AVRs).

Comment: You'll need to go back about 30 years for that one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intel 8080 family of processors used a parallel bus that, among other things, had separate strobes for read and write cycles.

The Motorola 6800 family of processors used a parallel bus that had a single R/W line to indicate whether a cycle was read or write, and a separate E (enable) strobe to indicate that a cycle was occurring.

It's trivial to convert between the two schemes (either way) with a few gates, but it was a big deal at the time that LCD controllers could connect to either style of bus without "glue" logic.

On a modern microcontroller, you're pretty much bit-banging the interface with GPIO pins anyway, so it's an arbitrary choice as to which style of bus you prefer to implement.

Comment: +1 for the historical perspective, especially the EE implications.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that makes (somewhat redundant) sense!

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit confusing because the data sheets for chips that support both parallel bus interfaces will rename (or dual name) the pins from the Motorola/Intel parallel bus conventions.

The "80 series CPU" bus timing diagram looks like this:

The parallel interface consists of 8 (or 15) bi-directional data pins (D7-D0) or (D15-D0), /RD, /WR and /CS. There's usually one or two address lines. (/WR and /RD timing is the same (just the resulting timing on the data bus changes), so the setup and hold timing for either line is shown on a single line in the below timing diagram.

[image]

The "68 series CPU" bus timing diagram looks like this:

The parallel interface consists of 8 (or 16) bi-directional data pins (D7-D0) or (D15-D0), /WR, /RD, and /CS. There's usually one or two address lines. (A0 and R/W timing is the same, so the setup and hold timing for either line is shown on a single line in the below timing diagram.

[image]

Both have a chip select and a data bus and usually an address line. The main difference is that the 68 bus has an E line and a R/W line, whereas the 80 bus has separate read and write lines.

Pick whichever is closer to the AVR parallel bus (if any) that is available on the chip you want to use. (I understand the AVR uses separate /WR and /RD lines when it does have such an interface, so it would be more like the 8080).

If you're implementing it with port pins (say the AVR has no external bus) it doesn't much matter which one you pick, as long as you are consistent and follow the timing and other rules.

Comment: No, note the difference between the so-called E line. The names are scrambled, as I mentioned.

Comment: It sure looked like you were correct. Re-wrote it, this deserves a good answer, it's a frequently asked question. Thanks.